# p5.js: resize canvas height when div changes height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, p5.js

I'm trying to make the canvas with p5.js resize together with a div in which it is in when clicking on a button that extends this div giving it additional height. I don't need the canvas to reload, instead I just need it to add some additional height. Is there a way to do it? I tried making the canvas width 100% and height: auto, but it doesn't work. Please, see the code below:

```
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
    <div id="canvas"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="button" id="extend-canvas">Extend</button>
```

Scripts:

```
function setup() {
    var myCanvas = createCanvas(498, 598);
    myCanvas.parent('canvas');
 }

$( "#extend-canvas" ).click(function() {
    var canvasHeight = $(".canvas-wrapper").height();
    $(".canvas-wrapper").height(canvasHeight + 300);
});
```

CSS:

```
.canvas-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    width: 500px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
}

#canvas canvas {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/207 Resize using c.size(width-10, height-10); (You have to load the p5.dom.js add-on to use the size method.)

Comment: This works, but the canvas reloads and becomes blank and all the information I add to it (I drew some lines with my mouse) disappears.

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/resizeCanvas

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `resizeCanvas()` function for this. More info can be found in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/resizeCanvas).

Here's an example that resizes the canvas to match the screen width and height:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 100, 200);
}

function windowResized() {
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

But you could also get the width and height of the div and set the canvas size to that.

Comment: @Kaori One way around that is to first draw everything to a buffer (the `createGraphics()` function is your friend), resize the canvas, then draw the buffer back to the canvas.

Comment: This works, but the canvas reloads and becomes blank and all the information I add to it (I drew some lines with my mouse) disappears.